# Não estou conseguindo usar libcurl C++

Tags: c++, libcurl, c++11, c++14, c++-builder

Galera, não estou conseguindo usar a libcurl!
alguem poderia me dar uma ajudinha?
me ensinar como compilar isso de forma correta!

Pois estou seguindo todos passos que vem em um doc junto com o proprio projeto. >>BUILD.WINDOWS.txt<<, Que se encontra dentro da pasta >>winbuild<<.

Segue vídeo dos passos que estou seguindo aqui pra compilar!
Eu consigo compilar normalmente, porém na hora de usar diz que as funções não foram definidas.

Como se eu não tivesse lincando a lib ao meu projeto!

Segue link >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cG5yA_fiBoY

Answer (score -1):

Então pessoal, consegui resolver!

relatar minha solução! 
Eu estava compilando a lib corretamente!
Porem estava tentando usar-la no Code::Blocks!
No Code::Blocks tem que fazer algumas configurações pra poder funcionar!

Já no Visual Studio 15 2017, funcionou sem fazer configuração nenhuma extra!
Basta liguar a lib ao projeto!

No Code::Blocks eu baixei a lib generica já compilada direto da pagina de download oficial da libcurl
Link >> https://bintray.com/artifact/download/vszakats/generic/curl-7.60.0-win32-mingw.zip
Já vem no formato certinho pra vc incluir dentro da pasta do compilador do Code::Blocks!
Ex:"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\"
Incluindo na pasta do compilador do Code::Blocks basta adicionar o include "curl/curl.h" e adicionar a seguinte flag >> -lcurl, ao seu projeto!
por ultimo vc deve compilar a lib no modo release pra poder ter acesso a dll, pra poder executar o arquivo compilado! 
dll vai pra mesma pasta do arquivo compilado!